# Restful URL - how to design a URL to update a resource based on property, not id

Tags: restful-url

If book is a resource, and the server assigns an id to every single book, we can think of the id as a resource id.

```
/POST /books/  - create a new book resource
/GET  /books/12345  - retrieve book resource with id 12345
/POST /books/12345  - update book 12345
```

But book resources can have some properties, like ISBN.
If I want to update a book resource based on given ISBN, how do I design the URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
/POST /books/isbn/{isbn_id}
```

or if you project just need isbn for the book identification, and not the id of each book, you can just replace book id with isbn id.

```
/POST /books/{isbn_id}
```

Comment: Hi Shukri, Thanks for your suggestion. If I am using both /POST /books/{id} and /POST /books/{isbn_id}, service can't know it's id or ISBN. If use /POST /books/isbn/{isbn_id}, looks like isbn is a type of resource, but it's just a property of book resource.

Comment: it's up to you how you want to design it, as long as you can handle it. another solution pass the isbn_id itself via POST form payload. so  it just `/POST /books/isbn`. isbn_id and all other information, you can pass on the body.